# What guarantees does zlib's inflate/deflate make about avail_in and avail_out?

Tags: compression, zlib, deflate, inflate, miniz

What guarantees does `zlib` give on the state of `avail_in` an `avail_out` after a call to `inflate`? I am seeing peculiar behaviour with `miniz` that I want to make sure is not a misunderstanding of the `zlib` API. Effectively, after calling `inflate`, I have `avail_in` non-zero, and `avail_out` also non-zero, so some input looks like it is not getting processed. More details below.

I have been using [miniz](https://github.com/richgel999/miniz) to inflate/deflate a file I stream to/from disk. My inflate/deflate loop is identical to the zlib sample in [zpipe.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zpipe.c), including using `MZ_NO_FLUSH`.

This loop has almost always worked, but today I inflated a stream deflated earlier and got an `MZ_DATA_ERROR` consistently. After adding the proper header though, `gzip` was able to inflate it fine and my data was intact.

The source of my issues came down to what would be the last call to `mz_inflate`. I include the typical inflate loop here:

```
/* decompress until deflate stream ends or end of file */
do {
    strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);
    if (ferror(source)) {
        (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
        return Z_ERRNO;
    }
    if (strm.avail_in == 0)
        break;
    strm.next_in = in;

    /* run inflate() on input until output buffer not full */
    do {
        strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
        strm.next_out = out;
        ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
        switch (ret) {
        case Z_NEED_DICT:
            ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;     /* and fall through */
        case Z_DATA_ERROR:
        case Z_MEM_ERROR:
            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
            return ret;
        }
        have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
        if (fwrite(out, 1, have, dest) != have || ferror(dest)) {
            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
            return Z_ERRNO;
        }
    } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

    /* done when inflate() says it's done */
} while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);
```

The inner `do` loop repeats until all of the current chunk has been processed and `avail_out` has extra room. However, on the last chunk of this particular stream, `inflate` did not return an error, but rather would reduce `avail_in` to some non-zero number, and would reduce `avail_out` *also* to some (other) non-zero number. So the inner `do` loop exits, as `avail_out` is non-zero, and we go try and get more data into `next_in` and `avail_in`, even though not all of `avail_in` has been processed, since `avail_in` is non-zero. This clobbers whatever was in `next_in` and `avail_in` and the `inflate` fails on the next call.

My workaround was to change the inner loop's termination condition from

```
strm.avail_out == 0
```

to

```
strm.avail_out == 0 || strm.avail_in > 0
```

but I have no idea if this is correct. I feel this may be a bug in `miniz` but am not sure. I would have thought that if `avail_in` indicated there was still data to be processed, that `avail_out` must be zero.

In case it is relevant: the input buffer size I am using is 512KB and the output buffer is 2MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `inflate()` returns `Z_OK` or `Z_BUF_ERROR`, and `avail_out` is *not* zero, then `avail_in` *is* zero.

Can you provide the compressed data in question?

Comment: Hey Mark, I won't have access to the data again until Monday but I can provide it then. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi Mark, I've confirmed that it is indeed a bug in miniz. Dropping in zlib directly did not exhibit the same problem. In case you're still interested, I've put the data up here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B51mmBvZmlNZaV95d2ZFMU9PT0E/view?usp=sharing